# Concept error or mistake in validation with livewire when save model

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've a problem with livewire 2.0 on Laravel 8.

I have created a registration page using a livewire component, and in it, I have implemented validation.

Once I click on the Register button, the action is not saved in the table.

I included a debug log, and in the debug itself if I see the correct action, and if I do it in tinker it is also correct.

I am getting desperate because I am not able to locate it, and the tests pass well.

This is the point in my [gitlab](https://gitlab.castris.com/root/tall-skeleton/-/tree/2545067b68994469602438f51b8aa420450787ca) where I have left the topic desperate.

```
protected $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'name' => 'required|min:6',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|same:passwordConfirmation'
];

public function register()
{

    $this->validate();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($this->password)
    ]);

    Log::debug($user);

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

#### Laravel.log

Debug write value of returned `User::create`

```
[2021-03-16 10:08:29] testing.DEBUG: {"name":"Foo","email":"foo@foo.com","updated_at":"2021-03-16T10:08:29.000000Z","created_at":"2021-03-16T10:08:29.000000Z","id":1}
```

#### On tinker

Work fine after verify database

```
$user = User::create([
'name' => 'Foo',
'email' => 'foo@email.com',
... 'password' => '123456']);
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.
=> App\Models\User {#4365
     name: "Foo",
     email: "foo@email.com",
     #password: "123456",
     updated_at: "2021-03-16 10:10:19",
     created_at: "2021-03-16 10:10:19",
     id: 4,
   }
```

Comment: did you check fillable ?

Comment: Yes. try with `protected $guarded = [];`or with `protected $fillable = ['name','email', 'password',];` Both fail @KamleshPaul

Comment: so validation is not working or insert is not working ? have u debug this

Comment: Validation work.If read code, thre're a log AFTER User::create() mehod. This is problem of post. I've edit title for best read.

Comment: so now all is good ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. my god. Despite in blade.

I forget create instance of **name** for verify.

Component of livewire, validates what is there, but does not validate if something is missing, and continues. It is something strange because the field that was missing name is no required really on database (nullable), but the create method does not return an error if value is empty, but also not save data in table.

#### Missing

```
<div>
    <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
        Name
    </label>
    <div class="mt-1 rounded-md shadow-md">
        <input wire:model="name" id="name" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="text"
               class="@error('name') border-red-500 @enderror appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
    </div>
    @error('name') <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div> @enderror
</div>
```

Now work fine.